# When to use “In” or “at”

Tags: grammar, prepositions

Which one is correct? If both were correct, in what cases they must be used? 
-In the doorway
-At the doorway. 
 For example: “He lingered in/at the doorway in hopes to cross paths with me” 
Which one should I use?

Comment: Have you looked at the definitions of these prepositions? Unless you expand this, to include sentences and context, there is no question here for anyone to answer.

Comment: Please edit your question if you need to.